# Javascript image element not conforming to new source

Tags: javascript, image

I have a series of pictures that are shown and controlled by "previous" and "next" buttons. each picture is shown through the same element, and the element source is changed by those buttons. When a picture's width is over 1100px, the element's width and height are changed. The problem is; once the element's dimensions are manually changed, each picture is forced to conform to those dimensions.

How do I force the element to automatically adjust its dimensions to the new source image after the element's dimensions were manually set in a previous photo?

Comment: Not clear. Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a browser will load an image based on its actual width and height just as long as the width and height attribute are not provided. So you could reload the entire image over again, except with the new src, like so:

```
<span id="dummyspan"></span>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function loadresizedimage(theimageurliwant) {
document.getElementById("dummyspan").innerHTML = "<img src='" + theimageurliwant + "' border='0'>";
}
</script>
```

The main downside to this, however, is that it isn't standard, and therefore isn't futureproof.
However, HTML5 fixes this problem with new attributes: naturalWidth and naturalHeight, accessible with Javascript.

```
<img src="mybeautifulartwork.jpg" name="belongsinamuseum" width="640" height="480" border="0">
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
// behold the amazing power of HTML5
document.images["belongsinamuseum"].width = document.images["belongsinamuseum"].naturalWidth;
document.images["belongsinamuseum"].height = document.images["belongsinamuseum"].naturalHeight;
</script>
```

Comment: sorry PM 77-1. My code has definitions and rules all over the place. To pick one section of code would raise more questions than just the one I was looking for; so I tried to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: tomysshadow: Thanks, this is what I was looking for; however, the naturalWidth and naturalHeight doesn't work on all browsers, right?And with the naturalWidth and Height, sometimes the images just do not show. Unless I can come up with some sort of fix to the code, or if you know of another way, I have to go with what isn't future proof. Thanks again.

Comment: HTML5 is new, so older browsers won't support it. Firefox should support it because they are usually right up to date with HTML5 stuff. As for IE, Chrome, Opera, Safari and the rest, according to my sources, all the most recent versions support naturalWidth. However, IE8 and lower doesn't support it. You could attempt to check if the variable "naturalWidth" exists first, and if not, use the alternate method.

Comment: Thanks again tomysshadow. I had to go with the innerHTML method. There were other problems, and the innerHTML didn't create new ones. I just have to rewrite bits of my code as time goes by.